# MySQL IN CLAUSE duplicates WANTED

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `courses` WHERE `id` IN ('. implode(",", $course[0]) .')';
```

This is the code I just had help with, I have used it before but the problem with it is, when something for example 1,1,2,3 is passed into the IN clause I will not get all values returned.

1x1
2x1
3x1

I want

1x2
2x1
3x1

All values must be returned otherwise it will mess up my table, any suggestions?

Comment: No, you don't want to get the same row returned twice. That doesn't provide you with any useful information. It's a waste of resources for no purpose. Rethink what you're doing and you'll delete this question.

Comment: My table requires 4 fields and if 3 return I get a messed up table.

Comment: What table? Your program's output? You can write code to repeat the row if you really need to for display purposes.

Comment: How would I do something like that? Because I really need the duplicates.

Comment: However you did it once, do it twice. If you want help with your display code, put that code in your question. You already know which rows to display more than once by the values of the $course[0] array.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that in SQL. Query by id and then use whatever language your are using to to do the 'multiplication'.